Need help in understanding Select Within Select with Where
I have the following code in C# LINQ and I am working on migrating to SQL. I don't have any experience with C# LINQ but for past few weeks I had been able to convert some of the functions.
But I hit upon the following code which I am trying to decipher the way I would implement it in SQL.

In the line 'qu.Category == Categories.History' - Is this filter applied before the join with Quiz or after? Join in terms of SQL.

How would I implement firstOrDefault in SQL - Just select Top 1 based on an order by column?


   var workflows = this.context.Quiz
        .AsSingleQuery()
        .Where(q => !q.Deleted)
        .Select(q => new
        {
            q,
            ValidResponse = q.Questions
                .Where(qu => qu.Category == Categories.History)
                .SelectMany(qu => qu.Responses)
                .Where(r => !r.Deleted)
                .Select(r => r.QuestionResponse).FirstOrDefault()
        })

If you could give me a converted SQL query for this, it would help my understanding!

Which dbms are you using?

Azure SQL Server

Waht are the definitions for qu.Category, Categories.History ? Navigation properties? You'd need to include DB context code as well. You can always inspect logs in the console log - there EF logs its queries upon sending them to db.

I understand definition would help you with join conditions and everything but conceptually how would it look based on the code. for e.g. using Id as a join condition for all the cases.

And I understand that EF logs can be used but problem is I don't have access to the deployed API nor the SQL DB which is being used. We are working with a copy of the database and code.

Use Linqpad. Make a connection to the context and run the query. I'm wondering: why "migrate to SQL"?

@GertArnold - They want to use the same data in Power BI reports. While OData is also a good way, it is not scalable enough for data analytics

This should be the sql used:
SELECT [q].*, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 [r].[QuestionResponse]
        FROM [Questions] AS [qu]
        INNER JOIN [Responses] AS [r] ON [qu].[Id] = [r].[QuestionId]
        WHERE [qu].[Category] = 'History' AND [r].[Deleted] = 0 AND [qu].[QuizId] = [q].[Id]
        ORDER BY [r].[Id]) AS [ValidResponse]
FROM [Quiz] AS [q]
WHERE [q].[Deleted] = 0

Guessing the FK columns and the Categories.History value

Ok. So the filter is applied on the inner query only and not on the total query. Thanks!

I do not believe the ORDER BY [r].[Id]) AS [ValidResponse] is covered by the original LINQ query. SQL tables do not have an implied order. The LINQ would need an explicit .OrderBy(r => r.Id) before the inner .Select(...).

@TN: true, added because it was missing in the query, doesn't make sense to return a random record.

I would agree with @TN . It would probably be better to explicitly point the flaw in the original Linq query rather than just the sql for the query that the OP should have written but didn't.
